# Pressure loss in concentric reducer with low Reynolds number and high viscosity fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

This is my first question in stack Exchange,I'm making the overall calculus por a piston dossifier of viscous fluid like Honey and Carob Syrup, and I am currently struggling with the minor losses of concentric reducers in my system,

**The picture from below is a concept of the system **
[image: Piston dossifier picture]
So in the system a plunger goes back and forth sucking and pushing the liquid from a three way valve which change it's state depending of the phase.

The current problem that i found that it seems to be that all the current formulas that i've found in for concentric reductions do not consider Reynolds factor but one ( https://neutrium.net/fluid-flow/pressure-loss-from-fittings-expansion-and-reduction-in-pipe-size/) However using the equations from the website ( I couldn't find a book yet that corroborates the equation) the head loss becomes too big and therefore the pressure drop in the reducers is ludicrous high.

**If you haven't read the website this is a sum up of the equations for K coefficient**
[image: If you haven't read the website this is a sum up of the equations for K coefficient]

As my system's Reynolds numbers do not go up from 20 you could imagine how much K rises, The equation by it's own seems to fit with normal reducers K value, considering how small is water viscosity and makes the Reynolds numbers which in turn make negligible the 160 value.

So as a conclusion i'll be glad to know if anybody knows another sources which considers Reynolds number for minor losses's elements ( like reducers)

The liquids which i'm working with have dynamic viscosity of 10 Pa.s and 60 Pa.s, therefore the low Reynolds number.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For that range of Re, if the convergence angle is small, you can assume that that, at each cross section, you have fully developed Poiseulle flow at the local diameter.  Then all you need to do is integrate the pressure gradient over the length of the converging section.

Comment: Hi Mr, Chet thanks for the comment, I have another doubt, what would happen if convergence angle is not small, lets say more than 45 degrees or when the fluid passing trough a reduced port ball valve?